# Stability of the null solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

Is there a differential equation:
$$\ddot x(t)=f(t, x(t)),\ f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2), \forall t\in \mathbb{R}\ f(t,0)=0;$$
that for any solution x(t) the following is true:
$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ (|x(0)|<\delta \implies \forall t\ge0\ |x(t)|<\epsilon)\ ?  $$

I guess that there is no such an equation. I have the following intuition. Let's look at the equation thinking that f is a force and x(t) is a coordinate of a particle that moves under that force. If we provide sufficiently enough initial speed $$\dot x(0)$$ to the particle, which is not limited, the particle will reach any high coordinate no matter where it was at the initial moment of time, because force f does not depend on the speed of the particle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are right: Assume that there is such an equation. Then, for  $\varepsilon =1$ there is some  $\delta >0$ such that for any solution $|x(0)|< \delta$ implies $|x(t)|<1$ $(t \ge 0)$. Now set
$$
c:= \max \{|f(t,\xi)|\mid (t,\xi) \in [0,1] \times [-1,1]\}.
$$
Let $x:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a solution with $|x(0)|< \delta$ and $x'(0)=1+ \delta + c/2$. Then, $|f(t,x(t))| \le c$ for each $t \in [0,1]$. Hence, for $t =1$ we have
$$
1 > |x(1)|= \left|x(0) +x'(0) + \int_0^1 \int_0^s f(\tau,x(\tau)) d\tau ds\right|
$$
$$
\ge |x'(0)| - |x(0)| - \int_0^1 \int_0^s |f(\tau,x(\tau))| d\tau ds
$$
$$
> |x'(0)| - \delta  - \frac{c}{2} =1,
$$
a contradiction.